# Angular2 Material Design Menu appears, but in wrong place and does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

My app uses Angular 2.0.1 and Angular Material 2.0.0-alpha.8-2. Per md-menu docs, I have attached a menu dropdown to a button in the md-toolbar header.  This header, a router-outlet link and a footer are the 3 elements in the AppComponent. Problem #1: When the button is clicked, the test menu appears, but it is below the footer, instead of being a dropdown from the button. I have tried x and y position with no results.  The dropdown contains anchor links to route to pages. Problem #2: When the anchor links are clicked, the dropdown disappears, but no routing to a new page occurs. These anchor links are also in the toolbar for test purposes, and the links and the router work correctly in the toolbar - outside the menu.  Here is relevant code.

```
<md-toolbar class="headerFooter"> <!--header toolbar element -->
  <span>
    <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">POST</button>
      <md-menu x-position="after" #menu="mdMenu">
        <a routerLink="/home" md-menu-item>Home</a><!--these links do not route-->
        <a routerLink="/rentApartment" md-menu-item>Rent an apartment</a>
        <button md-menu-item>RefreshTest</button>                           
     </md-menu>
  </span>

  <span><!-- to test routing - these links route properly-->
    <div>
      <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
      <a routerLink="/rentApartment">Rent apartment</a>
    </div>
  </span>
  others, etc.
</md-toolbar> <!--end of header toolbar component -->

<div class="partialPage">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<md-grid-list cols="6" rowHeight="100px" class="headerFooter"> <!--footer grid-list element -->
  <md-grid-tile><button md-button>TERMS</button></md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile><button md-button>PRIVACY</button></md-grid-tile>
  others, etc.
</md-grid-list>
```

What needs to change?

Comment: The best explanation, so far, is that is a fault/bug in the alpha.8-2 release. The bug report is #1387.  Here is a plunker that shows the 2 problems.  https://plnkr.co/PEpSF37IIyOgHV8DVhGN  My thanks go to rbostock for creating it.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I see the bug report was closed becouse of missing core styles. But I have tried with @import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css'; and still get the same position problem you have here.

Comment: I'm now using MD2.0.0-beta.1 and the menu still appears outside the page at the bottom.  I have given up on md-menu.  I'm going to try md-select, though it is not yet very stable.  FWIW, my testing indicates that deeppurple-amber is not fully correct. I could be wrong, but it doesn't work for my code.  The only theme that works for me is the purple-pink one (whatever). It clashes with my color scheme, but I'll change it someday when the MD2 team releases stable code for themes.

Comment: Could I ask where you include the deeppurple-amber? I included it in the /app/app.component.scss. But when I moved it to the /styles.scss it seemed to work. Everythign else worked fine in both location except the menu location.

Comment: I put this statement:  @import '/node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css';  in the CSS file that styles the HTML.